# How slowly fill color of a menu item?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, menu

On this [site](http://pnp.azurewebsites.net/en-us/) I liked the menu (on the right -windows, -phone, -alm, etc.) And I have no idea how to do it. I do not need all implementation. Just tell me by what framework or library I can make a similar menu. I use asp .net mvc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can CSS3 properties as mentioned in other example but they might not work in all browsers. You can choose to use jquery animate method to have similar effect.

```
 $("div").mouseenter(function(){
   $(this).css('background-color','red');
 $(this).animate({
 width:'250px'
 }, "slow");
 });

   $("div").mouseleave(function(){
   $(this).css('background-color','');
 $(this).animate({
 width:'50px'
 }, "slow");
 });
```

See the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LCcLr/1/